# Class not found in PHPUnit but recognized by Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit

When I run PHPUnit in my project, I come across with this issue.

**$ vendor/bin/phpunit**

```
PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Estring(29) "PHPFuzzy\Models\CriterionList"


Time: 59 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) FuzzyAHPTest::testDefineDecisionMaker
Error: Class 'PHPFuzzy\Models\CriterionList' not found

~/Documents/PHPFuzzy/tests/FuzzyAHPTest.php:10

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

**tests/FuzzyAHPtest.php**

```
use PHPFuzzy\Models\{FuzzyNumber as §, DecisionMaker, Criterion, CriterionList, Alternative, AlternativeList};
use PHPFuzzy\{ FuzzyMCDM, Utils };
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FuzzyAHPTest extends TestCase{
    public function testDefineDecisionMaker(){
        var_dump(CriterionList::class);
        $subcriteria1 = new CriterionList([
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 1"),
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 2"),
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 3")
        ]);
        $subcriteria2 = new CriterionList([
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 4"),
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 5"),
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 6"),
            new Criterion("SubCriteria 7")
        ]);
        $criteria = new CriterionList([
            new Criterion("Criteria 1", $subcriteria1),
            new Criterion("Criteria 2", $subcriteria2)
        ]);
        $alts = new AlternativeList([
            new Alternative("Kia"),
            new Alternative("Nissan"),
            new Alternative("Alfa Romeo")        
        ]);
        $dm = new DecisionMaker("Decision Maker 1", $criteria);
        $AHPSess = FuzzyMCDM::AHP($dm, $alts, $pcml);

        d($AHPSess->listPCMCombinations());
        // $this->assertEquals($expected->getMatrix(), $a->getMatrix());
    }


}
```

**in composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "bahadircyildiz/phpfuzzy",
    "description": "Fuzzy Logic library.",
    "keywords": ["fuzzy", "logic", "library"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Bahadir Can Yildiz",
            "email": "mail@bahadircyildiz.com"
        }
    ],
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "markrogoyski/math-php": "^0.39.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "kint-php/kint": "*"
    },
    "suggest":{
        "ext-operator": "Enables FuzzyNumber class to use arithmetic operators."
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PHPFuzzy\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev":{
        "psr-4": {
            "PHPFuzzy\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "conflict": {
        "phpunit/php-timer": ">=2"
    }
}
```

And this is my **File Structure**

```
src/
  MCDM/
    FuzzyAHP.php
  Models/
    Alternative.php
    AlternativeList.php
    Criterion.php
    CriterionList.php
    ...
tests/
  FuzzyAHPtest.php
  ...
```

To sum up, I can dump the **CriterionList** classname, but when I want to create an instance, it can't find the class. On the other hand, Visual Studio Code references the class.

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't care about your `composer.json`. It reads all the files in the project no matter if they are used or not. The PHP interpreter, on the other hand, starts by reading the file provided in the command line then it loads each file when it is `include`/`require`-d. When it encounters a class it doesn't know it invokes the autoloader(s) that, in turn, find the file that defines the class and load(s) it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Composer didn't generate autoload files properly. Using `composer update` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json file change this line

```
    "autoload-dev":{
        "psr-4": {
            "PHPFuzzy\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

to

```
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            
        }
    },
```

Then run and re-run your tests.

```
composer update
```